# How to add a fat/uber jar as dependency in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, uberjar

I'm newbie on maven.

My question is this:

I have a far jar in nexus, and want to add it as dependency in a pom.xml.
How can I do that?

[image]

In nexus there are both the jar and the fat jar.

Inside my pom.xml I'm using:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.sar</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-connector</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

and, of course, it is not downloading the fat jar.
How do I fix that?

Comment: Are you uploading the the normal jar and fat jar with the same group id, artifact and version? If so, there is no way for the dependent project to distinguish them. You should [upload the fat jar to nexus using a classifier](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-artifact-classifiers), which will allow the child project to select whether they want the fat jar or the normal one.

Comment: Good point. It is working. Thanks, It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Using a classifier is the right way to go:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.xxxxxxxxxxxx.sar</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-connector</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>fat</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I would check if the fat is a consumable artifact.

Comment: yep, this is the solution, btw the comment from Michael is the first mandatory step.

Answer (score -1):

add the dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>

<groupId>com.xxxxxxxx</groupId>

<artifactId>example-app</artifactId>

<version>1.0</version>

<scope>system</scope>

<systemPath>${basedir}/lib/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
```

Comment: System scope is deprecated. Don't use it. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#system-dependencies